# Raise event when rectangle movement starts

Tags: jointjs

I want to implement an undo action for the movement of the rectangles.
     For that i need the initial position of the rectangle.
     I tryed with "pointerdown", but this fires also when a rectangle is just selected and not moved.
     Is there a way to save the position only when movement starts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rappid's [dia.CommandManager](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.1/dia.html) to travel the history. This includes elements movements.

> CommandManager keeps track of graph changes and allows you to travel
>   the history of those changes back and forth. There is no limitation
>   put into the number of levels one can undo/redo.
>
> Installation Include joint.dia.command.js to your HTML:
>
> ```
> <script src="joint.dia.command.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Creating CommandManager
>
> ```
> var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
> var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({ el: $('#paper'), width: 500, height: 500, model: graph });
>
> var commandManager = new joint.dia.CommandManager({ graph: graph });
>
> $('#undo-button').click(function() { commandManager.undo(); });
> $('#redo-button').click(function() { commandManager.redo(); });
> ```
>
> (source : http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.1/dia.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I improved my answer